# Disabling Switched Outlet at the Switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle

I currently have a 3-switch box (as a single unit) that controls fan, fan light, and one switched outlet, but want to disable to switched outlet and leave the other two functional. The switch seems to have the black hot wire wired together with a nut to the other black wires with an additional single wire that leads to the switch as it's common. From there each switch leads to the respective object being powered (either red or black).

I managed to get the fan and fan light working, but I'm not sure how to wire the outlet back into the circuit as always-on.

Would I wire the outlet's red wire to the hot wire? And its black to... the hot wire also? Or do I wire in only the black or only the red to the hot? (What would I do with the other?) Or am I stuck with it permanently switched or permanently off?

Note: Both outputs on the outlet turn on and off on the same switch (and the outlet itself has its tab unbroken)

Thanks!

Comment: You really need to post pictures of the wiring on the switches in the box.  Trying to decipher your descriptions is giving me a headache.  It is a simple matter of tying the hot to the outlet to the hot going into the switches.

Comment: Without pics, the best I can suggest would be to remove the two wires from the outlet switch and nut them together.  If there's a ground wire attached to the switch, nut that to any other ground in the box.  Leave the fan/light switch wires alone.